# How to disable context menu default right-click behaviour?

Tags: c#, winforms

I desperately need to get rid of the context menu's right click handler. I wanna have full control over the context menu and I don't want it to reappear every time user right clicks even if it was already open... Is there any way to disable context menu's own right click handler?

Comment: Is there a specific control you need to disable this for?

Comment: well I have attached my own right click handler to glControl on which I draw my graphics but it seems that as soon as the context menu has been created for the first time, the next right clicks are invoked by the context menu itself rather than my glControl until context menu is closed.